# Importing an instantiated class sets global prototype

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, es6-class

Given the following react component, I am able to import the following component from multiple components. I'm confused on why after importing into each module and calling increment, it will increment the value as if it were the same instance. I don't think it's attached to the 'window', because I did some inspection.

Could this be, because this sets a global prototype? That still doesn't explain why it's seemingly updating the same instantiated class.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class FeatureFlags extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super (props);
    this.featureFlagList = [ 'test': true ];
    this.i = 0;
  }

  get showFeatureFlagList () {
    return this.featureFlagList;
  }

  increment () {
    this.i++;
    return this.i;
  }

  setList (list) {
    this.featureFlagList = list;
    return this.featureFlagList;
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div></div>
    );
  }
}

export default new FeatureFlags;

//First component - 
import FeatureFlags from './FeatureFlags';
console.log('first module ',  FeatureFlags.increment() );  //Logs 1

//Second component
import FeatureFlags from './FeatureFlags';
console.log('second module ',  FeatureFlags.increment() );  //Logs 2
```

Comment: I might be grossly naive here, but I don't see the `new` keyword other than the export, I'd be inclined to say it's the same instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's because you

```
export default new FeatureFlags;
```

That's one single *instance*! Importing the module multiple times will always import the same value.

Instead, you should always export the class:

```
export default class FeatureFlags extends Component { … }
```

and instantiate it in the other modules as often as you need it:

```
import FeatureFlags from './FeatureFlags';
const myLocalFlags = new FeatureFlags;
console.log('first module ', myLocalFlags.increment());  //Logs 1
```

Comment: 'Importing the module multiple times will always import the same value'?? Mind blown. If I used the export class syntax, would i have to call new to instantiate a new one?

Comment: this is the behavior i'm after (to have it shared as one instance). I just needed to know why it worked. How would i keep my existing code and render this component? <FeatureFlags /> throws a react error. Removing new fixes this problem, but breaks my original intention of keeping it shared as one instance.

Comment: I think React requires its components to be classes, so that it can instantiate them whenever necessary. I think you should explicitly create a global state store, and use that (pass that to) all usages of the component.

Comment: This module was not intended to be a container component (thinking redux), where it required some kind of store. I wanted to keep it contained within this module, for less boilerplate and dependency.

Comment: If you want to do it in a hacky fashion, just place a static mutable variable in the module scope and manipulate that. Zero boilerplate and dependencies, and it's obvious on sight that it's not a clean redux component :-)

Comment: `var i = 0; export class FeatureFlags { increment() { return ++i; } …}`